# Bundling not happening when deployed to production server

Tags: c#-4.0, optimization, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a bundle. However its not working when deployed to production server. I am running MVC4 RC

My bundle looks like

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/core").Include("~/Scripts/min/jquery-1.*",
           "~/Scripts/min/core.js",
          "~/Scripts/min/business-signup.js",
          "~/Scripts/min/slider.js",
          "~/Scripts/min/label-text.js",
          "~/Scripts/min/consumer-account.js",
          "~/Scripts/min/modernizr-2*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/min/css").Include(
            "~/Content/min/core.css",
            "~/Content/min/layout.css",
            "~/Content/min/reset.css",
            "~/Content/min/sprite.css",
            "~/Content/min/pricing.css",
            "~/Content/min/homepage-slider.css",
            "~/Content/min/transactions.css"));

    }
```

From my layout I call the bundles like

```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/min/css","~/Content/min/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/core")
```

However there is no minifaction or bundling happening. Instead a single request is made for each of the items within the the bundles.

I know the server is working correctly as I have another site running on the same server and the bundling is working ok.

Can anyone see something obvious to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are running in Release mode (`debug="false"` in your web.config). Also notice that [there is a bug](http://todd-carter.com/post/2012/06/10/Mini-Me-fication-in-SystemWebOptimization-RC-is-Evil.aspx) in the RC that prevents of properly caching the resources server side and thus increasing the CPU usage of your site everytime a request is made to the url that is supposed to serve the bundled and minified version of your resources.

Comment: Thanks Darin. That was the problem. Strange as both web configs are the same and the prod settings for the deployment are also the same.

Comment: Yes, having the same web.config in both development and production environments could be very bad.